# One trendline for multiple series

Tags: charts, google-visualization, trendline

Hello I have this simple example with 2 data series and 2 trendiness.

http://jsfiddle.net/ttwqazav/

I want to have only 1 trendline for both of them, as an average! Is that possible?

```
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
      [0, 0, 2],
      [1, 2, 4],
      [2, 4, 5],
      [3, 6, 8],
      [4, 8, 10],
      [5, 10, 12],
      [6, 12, 14],
      [7, 14, 16],
      [8, 16, 18],
      [9, 18, 20],
      [10, 20, 22]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 500,
      legend: 'none',
      colors: ['#9575cd', '#33ac71'],
      pointShape: 'diamond',
      trendlines: {
        0: {
            color:'red',
          type: 'linear',
          pointsVisible: false
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify data points as below:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['X', 'Y'],
  [0, 0],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 4],
  [3, 6],
  [4, 8],
  [5, 10],
  [6, 12],
  [7, 14],
  [8, 16],
  [9, 18],
  [10, 20],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 4],
  [2, 5],
  [3, 8],
  [4, 10],
  [5, 12],
  [6, 14],
  [7, 16],
  [8, 18],
  [9, 20],
  [10, 22]
]);
```

But you cannot differentiate between the two sets of data points!
If your aim is to get average best fit line, it'll work. :)